# Mod_rewrite to remove PHP extension and redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've read and tested many solutions, but couldn't get working correctly.

**WHAT I NEED?**

If user type in address bar `.../etc.php` It should be redirected to `.../etc/`, also `.../etc/` should be able to access directly, some examples:

`www.mysite.com/index.php` - > `www.mysite.com/`

`www.mysite.com/register.php` - > `www.mysite.com/register/`

`www.mysite.com/profile.php?id=123` - > `www.mysite.com/profile/123/`

Also if `lang` parameter is set to `en` (only  `en`, otherwise not show `lang` value at address bar) It should add `/en/` after root, something like:

`www.mysite.com/register.php?lang=en` - > `www.mysite.com/en/register/`

`www.mysite.com/index.php?lang=en` - > `www.mysite.com/en/`

---

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# url is ONLY '/en' or '/de' -> redirect to /en/ or /lt/ (adding slash)
RewriteRule ^(en|lt)$  $1/ [R=301,L]

# now all urls have en/ lt/ -> parse them
RewriteRule ^(en|lt)/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1&%{query_STRING} [L]
# no "R=301" here --------------------------------------^

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

But the code above let user access both `www.mysite.com/register.php` and `www.mysite.com/register/`, whereas It should redirect (change url) from `www.mysite.com/register.php` to `www.mysite.com/register/`

Comment: Try this condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f`

Comment: @Nawin If I append `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f` in bottom of my `.htaccess` file - nothing happens. If I delete all other rules and leaving only `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f` then I can access `www.mysite.com/register.php`, but not redirecting, also can't access anymore `www.mysite.com/register/`, so this not worked.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php  [R=301,L]` I think you trying to remove your extension so you can try this

Comment: @Nawin I've replaced `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]` with `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [R=301,L]`, but still the same, not removing `.php` extension.

Comment: @anubhava yes, there could be multiple parameters.

Comment: ok, there are just so many requirements in your question. I suggest you keep things simple and ask 1 or 2 question in one thread.

Comment: @anubhava but looks like It almost working. Main problem is that not redirecting from `etc.php` to `etc/`, both of them are accessible. Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest this redirect rule that removed `.php` extension and `index.php` from URLs:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[/\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2/ [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but looks like It not working. I've tried to remove all my code and left just your suggest in following `Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[/\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2/ [R=302,L,NE]`, but not working. I can access `www.mysite.com/etc` at all now, working only with PHP extension like: `www.mysite.com/etc.php`. I've tried to append this to end of file, but in this way If I access `www.mysite.com/etc` it adding .php, not removing extension

Comment: And If I'm trying to access `www.mysite.com/etc/` It redirecting to `www.mysite.com/etc/.php`. It should be reverse, remove `.php` extension, not append.

Comment: Now I receive `Internal Server Error. The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.` This `.htaccess` file is stored in `public_html` (root) in the same directory as `index.php`, I've kept only your updated code.

Comment: I've checked an error log, I got this one: `/public_html/.htaccess: Either all Options must start with + or -, or no Option may.`

Comment: If I remove `Options -MultiViews` error gone, but I can't access anymore `www.mysite.com/etc/`, only `www.mysite.com/etc.php` with `.php` extension.

Comment: Replaced file with your code, but not working, cannot access `www.mysite.com/etc/` at all, only `www.mysite.com/etc.php` is available.

Comment: I called for my hosting administrator, looks like there was error in server configuration. It almost working, but there is something wrong. If I'm trying to access for example: `www.mysite.com/something` Its working correctly. If I'm trying to access `www.mysite.com/something/` with trailing slash, It not showing CSS. And If I'm trying to use `www.mysite.com/something.php` Ir redirecting It to `www.mysite.com/something/` with trailing slash and not loading CSS, where's the problem?

Comment: Ok we can solve this problem :) Add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: Thanks, It worked. But not working with parameters. For example if `lang` parameter used:`www.mysite.com/register.php?lang=en`should be converted to `www.mysite.com/en/register/` and if any otheer parameters used like `www.mysite.com/etc.php?id=123&param=abc` should be converted to: `www.mysite.com/etc/123/abc/`

Comment: To achieve It, I've used before my code posted in question, now concatenated with your code, but something wrong. Now for example If I have `www.mysite.com/register.php?lang=en` It redirecting me to `www.mysite.com/register/?lang=en`

Comment: Now recall my comments below your question where I suggested to keep one problem per thread. This solution only handles removing `.php` from URLs and internally routes it to correct php file. It doesn't handle parameters at present. I suggest you ask that in a new question with clear requirements and I will try to address that in a new answer.

Comment: I've asked another question, to be clear. This one accepting as correct answer. Thank you very much for you help. Another questions is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44184455/mod-rewrite-for-website-translating-via-htaccess