# Mod_rewrite for website translating via htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've already done with hiding PHP extension via `.htaccess`.

`lang` parameter could be `en` or `lt`

If `lang` parameter's value = `en` than should add `en/` after domain like that:

`www.mysite.com/register.php?lang=en` ->`www.mysite.com/en/register/`

If `lang` parameter's value = `lt` than should be like that:

`www.mysite.com/register.php?lang=lt` ->`www.mysite.com/register/`

If any other parameter is used, should be like that:

`www.mysite.com/etc.php?id=123&param=abc` -> `www.mysite.com/etc/123/abc/`

My `.htaccess` looks like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# url is ONLY '/en' or '/lt' -> redirect to /en/ or /lt/ (adding slash)
RewriteRule ^(en|lt)$  $1/ [R=301,L]
# now all urls have en/ lt/ -> parse them
RewriteRule ^(en|lt)/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1&%{query_STRING} [L]
# no "R=301" here --------------------------------------^

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[/\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2/ [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

But now It working incorrectly:

If I have `www.mysite.com/register.php?lang=en` It redirecting me to `www.mysite.com/register/?lang=en`

Have you any ideas?

Comment: Can you have `www.mysite.com/etc.php?lang=en&id=123&param=abc` also? If yes then what URL should it be redirected to?

Comment: @anubhava Yes, always if there is `lang=en` it should go after domain like that: `www.mysite.com/en/...` so in case you've asked: `www.mysite.com/en/etc/123/abc/`.

Comment: Hmm that makes rewriting job really difficult because first part after host-name can be sometimes a language code or a php file name. Can there be `/ft/` or `/de/` or `/it/` also at the start same as `/en/` in the same URL?

Comment: There are only 2 languages - `lt` or `en`, but `lt` is default, my domain really is like `mysite.lt` so if `lt` language I dont need to add It. If `lt` language so `www.mysite.lt/etc/` if `en` then `www.mysite.lt/en/etc/`.

Comment: @anubhava ok, thank you for trying to help.

Comment: @anubhava I thought that It will be dynamically. That many GET parameters I pass that will generate in following automatically: `www.mysite.lt/en/etc/123/abc/foo/bar/...` if there is static, will be good for now `lang`, `id` and `param`.

Comment: GET parameters cannot be dynamic because you're only keeping values in URL but their names have to come from somewhere. e.g. 1st value is for param `lang`, 2nd value is for param `id` and 3rd value is for name `param`. If your routing becomes too complex then I suggest just route everything to `index.php` and handle routing in your PHP code.

Comment: @anubhava got It, so let's do It for 3 `GET` parameters - `lang`, `id` and `param`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your root .htaccess like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php\?lang=(lt)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php\?lang=(en)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %2/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php\?lang=(en)&id=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %2/%1/%3? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php\?lang=(en)&id=([^\s&]+)&param=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %2/%1/%3/%4? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+\.php)\?lang=lt&(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1?%2 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)&param=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2/ [R=302,L,NE]

# url is ONLY '/en' or '/lt' -> redirect to /en/ or /lt/ (adding slash)
RewriteRule ^(en|lt)$ $1/ [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang=(en|lt)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!(?:en|lt)/)(.+)$ lt/$1 [DPI,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(en|lt)/([\w-]+)/?$ - [L]

# now all urls have en/ lt/ -> parse them
RewriteRule ^(en|lt)/([\w-]+)/?$ $2.php?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(en|lt)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $2.php?lang=$1&id=$3 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(en|lt)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $2.php?lang=$1&id=$3&param=$4 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Than you for an answer, but It didn't work. When I'm trying to access `www.mysite.lt` I got an error: `The requested URL /lt/ was not found on this server.`

Comment: It almost working, except with `lang=lt`. If I pass to address bar like: `http://mysite.lt/register.php?lang=lt&id=123456789&param=abcd` It not converting url to `http://mysite.lt/register/123456789/abcd`, but If I'm using `lang=en` It working normally `http://mysite.lt/register.php?lang=en&id=123456789&param=abcd` converting to `http://mysite.lt/en/register/123456789/abcd`, something wrong when `lang` parameter is `lt`

Comment: Hey, I got another problem when trying to change language via button clicks. I have asked another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44247981/mod-rewrite-htaccess-for-web-translating