# Mod_rewrite .htaccess for web translating

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

For now I have `.htaccess` figured out like that:

`lang` parameter could be `en` or `lt`

If `lang` parameter's value = `en` than It adding `en/` after domain like that:

`www.mysite.com/register.php?lang=en` ->`www.mysite.com/en/register/`

If `lang` parameter's value = `lt` than it is like that:

`www.mysite.com/register.php?lang=lt` ->`www.mysite.com/register/`

If any other parameter is used, is like that:

`www.mysite.com/etc.php?id=123&param=abc` -> `www.mysite.com/etc/123/abc/`

When I type it directly to address bar it working correctly, but problem is when clicking button to change language. I have navigation and buttons to change language like that:

```
if (!empty($_GET['lang']))
{   
    setcookie('lang', $_GET['lang']);

} 
<form action="" method="get">      
    <input id="lang-lt" type="submit" name="lang" value="lt">
    <input id="lang-en" type="submit" name="lang" value="en">
</form>

<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="register.php">Register</a>
```

When `lt` or `en` button is clicked It working incorrectly and url looks like:

`www.mysite.lt/register/?lang=en` or `www.mysite.lt/?lang=en` or `www.mysite.lt/?lang=lt`

instead of

`www.mysite.lt/en/register/` or `www.mysite.lt/en/` or `www.mysite.lt/`

`.htaccess` file for now looks like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php\?lang=(lt)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php\?lang=(en)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %2/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php\?lang=(en)&id=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %2/%1/%3? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php\?lang=(en)&id=([^\s&]+)&param=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %2/%1/%3/%4? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+\.php)\?lang=lt&(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1?%2 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)&param=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2/ [R=302,L,NE]

# url is ONLY '/en' or '/lt' -> redirect to /en/ or /lt/ (adding slash)
RewriteRule ^(en|lt)$ $1/ [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang=(en|lt)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!(?:en|lt)/)(.+)$ lt/$1 [DPI,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(en|lt)/([\w-]+)/?$ - [L]

# now all urls have en/ lt/ -> parse them
RewriteRule ^(en|lt)/([\w-]+)/?$ $2.php?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(en|lt)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $2.php?lang=$1&id=$3 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(en|lt)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $2.php?lang=$1&id=$3&param=$4 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Have you idea where is the problem?

Comment: Since you only seem to have two languages, why don't you just link directly to the canonical URL (and style them as buttons if you wish)? (Presumably you have already changed your in-app URLs to the canonical URL? Although your HTML above suggests that maybe you haven't and are relying on a redirect in `.htaccess`??)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your top 2 redirect rules to this:

**Complete .htaccess:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:(?:index|(.+))\.php)?\?lang=lt\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^.?]+)/?\?lang=lt\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:(?:index|(.+))\.php)?\?lang=(en)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %2/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^.?]+)/?\?lang=(en)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %2/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php\?lang=(en)&id=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %2/%1/%3? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php\?lang=(en)&id=([^\s&]+)&param=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %2/%1/%3/%4? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+\.php)\?lang=lt&(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1?%2 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)&param=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2/ [R=302,L,NE]

# url is ONLY '/en' or '/lt' -> redirect to /en/ or /lt/ (adding slash)
RewriteRule ^(en|lt)$ $1/ [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang=(en|lt)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!(?:en|lt)/)(.+)$ lt/$1 [DPI,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(en|lt)/([\w-]+)/?$ - [L]

# now all urls have en/ lt/ -> parse them
RewriteRule ^(en|lt)/$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(en|lt)/([\w-]+)/?$ /$2.php?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(en|lt)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /$2.php?lang=$1&id=$3 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(en|lt)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /$2.php?lang=$1&id=$3&param=$4 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this time something wrong. If I type `www.mysite.lt/en/` I got `404 error - Not Found`. Also If I go to `www.mysite.lt/register/` and trying to change language to `en` I got address like `www.mysite.lt/register/?lang=en` and the same error.

Comment: For now looks like `lt` button not working at all, It refreshing page, but language not changing. If I click `en` button once, Its ok, address bar looks like `www.mysite.lt/en/`, but If I click `en` button second time, it adding `en/` one more time, address bar looks like `www.mysite.lt/en/en/` and I got error `Not Found`. Maybe there is problem with my buttons?

Comment: I provided buttons definitions in my question. Buttons to change language are passed to form with `method="get"`.Button to enter to `register.php` looks like `<a href="register.php">Register</a>`. About errors I don't receive any, just `lt` button not changing language.

Comment: And about problem when second time clicked `en` button adding second `en/` like `www.mysite.lt/en/en/` looks like problem with `.htacccess`?

Comment: `<base href="/" />` is included in both pages `index.php` and `register.php` below `<head>` section. I don't receive any errors. You could check live at http://supercv.lt maybe you'll notice what's wrong. How about this `What URL do you send to web-server and what error are you getting etc`? What do you mean `what URL do you send`? On clicking submit button I send `$_GET["lang"];` which can be equal to `en` or `lt`, also setting cookie with this value.

Comment: Thanks, It's almost fine, just now if I'm trying to change language from `www.supercv.lt/register/` page it redirecting me to root `www.supercv.lt/`, really It should stay on the same page (if clicked from `register.php` it should change address to `www.supercv.lt/en/register/` also if I change language to `en` and after It clicking `register` button, It redirecting me to Lithuanian version `www.supercv.lt/register/` instead of `www.supercv.lt/en/register/`

Comment: Now the same problem as before, `lt` button stopped working, `en` button after clicking twice adding `/en/en/` which was solved by adding `<form action="/"`. And when changed language for example to `en` and current address is `www.supercv.lt/en/register/` and clicking on `Home` button it redirecting to `www.supercv.lt/` instead of `www.supercv.lt/en/`.

Comment: Looks like I have to change something too with `Home` and `Register` buttons here `<a href="register.php">Register</a>`

Comment: I solved problem with buttons something like: `<a href="register.php?lang=$lang">Register</a>`. Now left problem with form action. If I use as you suggested before `<form action="/"` than from `register.php` when trying to change language It redirecting to `index.php`, if I use `<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];?>" method="get">` then `lt` button not working and `en` adding multimple `/en/en/`. have you ideas about this?

Comment: My HTML form looks like good when using `<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];?>" method="get">`, I've removed all code from `.htaccess` and It successfully passing get parameter. `http://supercv.lt/register.php?lang=lt` if clicking `en` button it change link to `http://supercv.lt/register.php?lang=en`, after It if clicking `Home` button, it change link to `http://supercv.lt/index.php?lang=en` I left for now website without `.htaccess` that you could test It. Seems problem is with `.htaccess` file. Maybe I need to register another question for this?

Comment: Sir, have you idea how to correct `.htaccess` to fix that?

Comment: Now I think you should just completely remove `<form...>` for changing language and keep 2 buttons only to change URLs. `en` button should change current page's URL to `'/en' . preg_replace('~^/(en|lt)~', '', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])`. And `lt` button should change current URL to: `preg_replace('~^/(en|lt)~', '', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])`

Comment: Finally! Thank you so much! ++++